# How to use web scraping and webview to get data from google trasnlate?

Tags: kotlin, web-scraping, android-jetpack-compose

I want to use web scraping to get dynamic data, adding text to a query, and receive the data related. In this case I'm trying to scrape google translate. Cuurently I'm able to add a text to the base url:

```
  val mUrl = "https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=ckb&op=translate"

    val uri = Uri.parse(mUrl).buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter("q", text)
            .build()


    AndroidView(factory = {
        WebView(it).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            webViewClient = WebViewClient()
            settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
            loadUrl(uri.toString())
        }
    }, update = {
        it.loadUrl(uri.toString())
    },)
```

I get the result in the webview, but what if I want to get the data as a string without needing to enter to the webview? Can anyone help me with that?